# How To Define Point Of Bit of IC 89c51 in keil c

Tags: embedded

I have query regarding to C language programming for robotics, I am facing difficulty for 
How To Define Point Of Bit of IC 89c51 in keil c for embedded c programming

Comment: What do you mean by "point"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use sbit p1;` for pointing 1st port

Answer (score 0):

in keil uVision, if you have selected AT89c51, in the C file if you right click, you can see

> insert "`#include <REGX51.h>`"

on clicking that

```
#include <REGX51.h>
```

will appear in the C file
in that all port registers' and individual pins' addresses are mapped to variables, eg : Port 0 to P0,
P0.1 to P0_1 etc.
then you can directly use those variables for accessing all registers, including Port registers and Port pins